# How to stop extjs treepanel from loading infinitely?

Tags: extjs4, treepanel

Finally after struggling with extjs tree panel, tree store and building custom reader to read and convert pentaho data for 2 weeks I have managed to load pentaho data into treepanel of extjs.

Now my Tree panel is loading same data infinitely. 
Treepanel looks as follows :

[image: treepanl screen shot]

Part of my json data looks as follows :

```
{
    {name: 'US', candidateCount: 3, children: []},
    {name: 'India', candidateCount: 922, children: [
       {name: 'Goa', candidateCount:124, children: []},
       {name: 'Maharashtra', candidateCount: 43, children: [
             {name: 'Pune', candidateCount: 3},
             {name: 'Mumbai', candidateCount: 33},
             {name: 'Kolhapur', candidateCount: 4},
             {name: 'XXX', candidateCount: 3},
        ]}
     ]},
    {name: 'UK', candidateCount: 1, children: []},
}
```

As you can see in image above, after expanding `India` node it has again loaded data of country level (i.e. country names US, uk, India, UK). Actually I want to show state level data like data of Maharashtra, Goa. Instead of that treepanel is again loading same data again.

How to avoid this kind of behavior? I have already set `leaf` property of US, uk and India nodes to `false`.

I tried setting `Expanded` property to `true` but then treepanel keeps loading same nodes again and again and my browser tab just gets hanged.

Please let me know how to avoid this? I want tree panel to load data only once.

---

EDIT - Solution to this problem

### I solved this problem by adding listener on `append` event of store and then setting `leaf` value to `true` for the nodes which I wanted to be leaf.

Comment: Hi can you share your store code? I'm having same behavior. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting data item to:

```
{
    ...
    leaf: true
}
```

will stop it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my treepanel and JSON data. My treeStore looks something like this:

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'urlJson',

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'instanceList',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    },

    root:{
        text: 'Root',
        expanded: true
    }
```

And the JSON

```
{
    "instanceList": [
        {
            "text": "Parent 1",
            "instanceList": [
                {
                    "class": "testing",
                    "id": 3,
                    "leaf": true,
                    "text": "Child 1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "Parent 2",
            "instanceList": [
                {
                    "class": "testing",
                    "id": 2,
                    "leaf": true,
                    "text": "Child 2"
                },
                {
                    "class": "testing",
                    "id": 1,
                    "leaf": true,
                    "text": "Child 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "instanceTotal": 1,
    "success": true
}
```

I changed "children" for "instanceList" and my treepanel stopped doing that infinitely loop, so I guess If you change "name" for "children" ?

Answer (score 2):

Loading trees can be tricking. Try setting `loaded: true` on those nodes. Before you start clicking around, is the tree properly loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all **parents that do not have any children** have **"leaf" set to "true"** OR 
have an **empty "children" node**.

AND **all children nodes** have **"leaf" set to "true"** (as already mentioned by Asken)

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that any child becomes a root to its dependents . So the root property and the children property MUST have the same NAME. I am very happy I found this tread. It saved my life I was about to shoot myself because of endless reloading the tree

Answer (score 0):

As Edd said, if you set in proxy custom rootProperty:'instanceList', you have to change all "children" in json to that property, ie 'instanceList'. It was my solution.