# ExtJs 4.2: TreePanel recursive root node load instead of children

Tags: tree, treeview, extjs4.2

Playing around with ExtJs v4.2.1 (trial) I could not build a complete treePanel from a JSON file. Every time you expanded/collapse a children, a request was made to the server which responded with the same JSON thus duplicating the root node.
First I needed the rood node to be interpreted from the JSON file and not hardcoded in the store, second the ajax request was just reading a JSON file to simulate a server response.

So after a lot of googling an reading Q/A here this is [What I've Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/):

- Checked all nodes for leaf=true/false ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312228/207603))
- Hardcoded root node in store
- Added loaded=true to nodes ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312209/207603))
- Added a reader to the proxy to point to the root node in the JSON response ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957791/207603))
- Played around with rootVisible=bool
  And many more ...

How to load the tree from a JSON including the childrens in this version of ExtJs (v4.2.1) ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't wanted to bind to an event and do a workaround, this had to work without any custom function or overwrite (there are a lot of workaround out there that are suggesting that).

So this is what worked for me:

view/Menus.js:

```
Ext.define('ExtApp.view.Menus', {

    extend      : 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias       : 'widget.Menus',
    store       : 'Menus',
    rootVisible : false,
    autoScroll  : true,
    xtype       : 'Menus',
    viewConfig  : {
        plugins     : { ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop' }
    },
    useArrows   : true,
});
```

store/Menus.js:

```
Ext.define('ExtApp.store.Menus', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    proxy   : {
        type    : 'ajax',
        url     : 'path/to/file.json'
    },
    root    : {
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

file.json (the . will not be loaded/visivle in the tree):

```
{
    text    : '.',
    children: [{
        text    :'m0',
        id      :'m0',
        leaf    :true
    },{
        text    :'m1',
        expanded: true,
        id      :'m1',
        children:[{
            text    :'m11',
            id      :'m11',
            leaf    :false,
            children:[{
                text    :'m111',
                id      :'m111',
                leaf    :true
            }]
        },{
            text    :'m12',
            id      :'m12',
            leaf    :false,
            children:[{
                text    :'m121',
                id      :'m121',
                leaf    :true
            }]
        },{
            text    :'m13',
            id      :'m13',
            leaf    :true
        },{
            text    :'m14',
            id      :'m14',
            leaf    :true
        }]
    },{
        text    :'m2',
        children:[{
            text    :'m21',
            id      :'m21',
            leaf    :true
        }]
    }]
}
```

Hope this will help others as I saw a lot of questions about similar issues with the tree panel.

Comment: If you have an error "config.init is undefined", the treeviewdragdrop plugin did not load everything it needs, so you need to manually require them, see http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264982-treepanel-cannot-be-created-after-having-upgraded-from-4.1.1-to-4.2.1&p=976166&viewfull=1#post976166